# Objects not displaying in render

Tags: animation

Hi I'm trying to make a river scene but the only thing that is showing up when I render is the object that I'm using as a fluid inflow.

Camera View
[image: Camera View]

Rendered
[image]

As you can see in the outliner everything other than the grass in enabled in render but for some reason it does not render.
Can anybody tell me why this is happening?
[Blender File](https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=RiverBed6.blend)

[image]

Comment: is it set to renderable , if yes then provide the file

Comment: have you parented the grass or checked normals with shift+N? not sure otherwise.

Comment: use this site: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I have provided a dropbox link

Comment: Also I noticed that the view that is being rendered isn't the same as what the camera views. As the camera is positioned so the inflow object cant be seen

Comment: Thanks I've uploaded to that site as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select object that is not rendered.
Go to *Properties Editor > Particle System > Render* > **Show Emitter**

[image]

Comment: it looks like it's not the only problem, his cube is Glass so I guess as he's in Eevee he needs to turn on Refraction for both Material and Render but I still can't make it work...

Comment: @moonboots He is using it as Fluid domain ...

Comment: ooh ok, don't know enough about it then   ;)

Comment: Thanks vklidu I haven't got a clue why show emitter was disabled and because the river bed, stones and ground was joined it all vanished(separated them previously when trying to fix the scene). I have noticed in this latest version of blender some object options are disabled. Like yesterday it took me a while to figure out why I was not getting water even though I set the box object to be inflow. Which was just the use inflow box not being checked.

Comment: @moonboots I wanted to vote as dupli, but I can't find any. Its always easier for me to create answer than spent much more time by searching for the same issue here ... grrr

Comment: @PaulSharrock I know that feeling :) Great if it helped.